# Merge solr results in a group to one array

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, facet, solrcloud

I have used group in **solr** querying and the results are as follows.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":157,
    "params":{
      "q":"name:Abcd",
      "hl":"true",
      "hl.simple.post":"</em>",
      "indent":"true",
      "group.limit":"-1",
      "hl.fl":"id,address",
      "rows":"332",
      "wt":"json",
      "hl.simple.pre":"<em>",
      "group.field":"uid",
      "group":"true"}},
  "grouped":{
    "sdn_uid":{
      "matches":10,
      "groups":[
        {
          "groupValue":"726",
          "doclist":{"numFound":5,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "address":"Bahia Ignacio #1921",
                "uid":"726",
                "idnumber":"ZAGI-500130",
                "id":"140",
                "name":"El ZAMBADA",
                "_version_":1584841227872763908},
              {
                "address":"Bahia Ignacio #1921",
                "uid":"726",
                "idnumber":"ZAGI-500130",
                "id":"141",
                "name":"Ismael ZAMBADA GARCIA",
                "_version_":1584841227872763909},
              {
                "address":"Bahia Ignacio #1921",
                "uid":"726",
                "idnumber":"ZAGI-500130",
                "id":"142",
                "name":"LOAIZA AVENDANO",
                "_version_":1584841227872763910},
              {
                "address":"Bahia Ignacio #1921",
                "uid":"726",
                "idnumber":"ZAGI-500130",
                "id":"143",
                "name":"Javier GARCIA HERNANDEZ",
                "_version_":1584841227873812480},
              {
                "address":"Bahia Ignacio #1921",
                "uid":"726",
                "idnumber":"ZAGI-500130",
                "id":"144",
                "name":"Ismael RENTERIA",
                "_version_":1584841227873812481}
           ]}]}

Here grouping is based on uid. But I need the result as follows :

"doclist":{"numFound":5,"start":0,"docs":[
              {
                "address":["Bahia Ignacio #1921","Bahia Ignacio #1921","Bahia Ignacio #1921","Bahia Ignacio #1921","Bahia Ignacio #1921"]
                "uid":["726","726","726","726","726"]
                "idnumber":["ZAGI-500130","ZAGI-500130","ZAGI-500130","ZAGI-500130","ZAGI-500130"]
                "id":["141","142","143","144","145"]
                "name":["El ZAMBADA","Ismael ZAMBADA GARCIA","LOAIZA AVENDANO","Javier GARCIA HERNANDEZ","Ismael RENTERIA"]
                "_version_":[1584841227872763908,1584841227872763909,1584841227872763910,1584841227873812480,1584841227872763908]}
]}
```

That is results found inside a group must be arranged in an array instead of showing them separately.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: That would be job of the library you're using to access Solr or the controller in your application making the request.

Comment: Is there any way to edit the output format (**not the case of xml/json format**) of solr ? There is "version" showing in the solr results, and I dont need that to show up.

Comment: You can create your own [responsewriter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/response-writers.html), or, depending on what you want to do, a [response transformer](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html). It does however sound like you're exposing Solr directly to your end users, which usually isn't a good idea.

Comment: If there is no way in getting the results as I said **normally**, then I need to make it like that using response writer. I'm a newbie and where is this response writer located and how to edit it according to my need ?

Comment: The [original JSON Response Writer is located here](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/response/JSONResponseWriter.java). You could probably extend it by introducing a new parameter that allows you to map a certain part of the structure to be the new element. But have you looked at whether `group.format=simple` does what you want? It'll return the _grouped result_ as the root element instead of inside a `grouped` key.